# Nekusar and the new damage redirection to planeswalkers

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

So to be clear, [Nekusar, the Mindrazer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNekusar%2c%20the%20Mindrazer%5d) only hits players with the newest rules change and no longer can hit Planeswalkers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.

Most cards that previously dealt damage to a player received errata to allow them to target a player or planeswalker, but as Nekusar’s ability is not targeted; the standard errata wouldn’t have made as much sense (mostly because you don’t choose or target a player).

You can see the current wording of any card in [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx); the wording there is what counts. And with the planeswalker damage redirection rule change; the question is simple for any card; because cards that can damage planeswalkers will specifically say so (or they will say "any target").

Comment: When in doubt, look at the text in Gatherer.  Gatherer lists the official, most up-to-date card text, so if a card can damage planeswalkers it will say so (or say "any target")